# Show input text for search among select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a select tag with multiple options. Suppose there are so many options so that it is not so convenient to search through them. I noticed when select is clicked and options are show, we can type some letter and select will jump to option which starts with this letter. I I type for example 'he', select jumps to the options that start with 'he' and so on.

But we do not see what we typed. Is there a way to show that typed text?

Comment: Something like Select2 plugins? https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you shouldn't pick a select if the user will need to search through the options. What about [tokeninput plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)?