# How to achieve edit functionality in @Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to have edit option in `@Html.DropDownListFor` in mvc3 so that I can trigger autocomplete `event(if exists)`. I have requirement to type and filter the contents of `@Html.DropDownListFor`

I'm looking for exactly like http://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/ functionality

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275744/show-input-text-for-search-among-select-options/31275800

Comment: Cleaned up, formatting